# Controle de sessions e autenticação no PHP com CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, login

Bom dia pessoal, sou novo na programação com `PHP` e estou com uma dúvida: já desenvolvi o sistema de login e está funcionando corretamente, agora eu gostaria de controlar o acesso às demais páginas da aplicação, ou seja o usuário só acessar páginas internas se tiver feito o login.

Sei também que para isso preciso usar um `if (isset(....))` mas minha dúvida é: onde eu coloco esse `if (isset(....))`?

Como estou utilizando o *Framework CodeIgniter* devo pôr essa cláusula no *Controller*, na *Model* ou na *View*?

Além disso, esta é minha estrutura após ter feito o login:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, meu *isset* ficaria dessa forma:

```
if(isset(usuario_logado[username]))
{
//usuário não logado direciona para a pagina de login
}
```

`$usuario_logado` é o *array* que recebe os dados do usuário após a autenticação com o banco de dados.

Comment: Só não pode nesse array disponibilizar a senha, isso caracteriza falha de segurança.

Comment: Nem em `controller`, nem em `model` nem na `view`. Use um `helper` ou um `hook` pra fazer isso com segurança. Um `hook` é mais seguro, pois será chamado em todas as instâncias para fazer a validação.

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada sobre Hooks, obrigado.

Comment: Pesquisa na minha resposta, é mais rápido :D

Comment: **Uma sugestão:** sua pergunta tem muito mais a ver com "autenticação" do que com "sessions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Habilite os [HOOKS](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html?highlight=hook#enabling-hooks) na sua aplicação. Esse mecanismo vai checar automaticamente e validar o logon sem precisar marcar nem fazer *includes*.

Use [SESSIONS](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-library). Eu sei que a biblioteca de sessão nativa do *CodeIgniter* não é uma maravilha, mas ela vai te ajudar em alguns momentos, então é melhor deixar ativada (eu gosto de [autoload](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html)). E mesmo que vc não queira usar a biblioteca nativa, **use $_SESSION** para armazenar as credenciais de logon.

> **Jamais, em hipótese alguma,** vc deve salvar a senha do usuário na sessão ou em cookies ou em qualquer outro local da memória. Nem mesmo o *HASH* da senha.

Depois de habilitar os *HOOKS* e a *SESSION*, vá até ***application/config/hooks.php*** e insira isso aqui:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = [
    'function' => 'logged',
    'filename' => 'logged.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
];
```

É simples: pra validar o logon, o *HOOK* precisa saber qual é o controlador e o método chamado, ou seja, o *CodeIgniter* tem que passar essa informação pra ele, e isso só é possível depois que os controladores já estão carregados, por isso `post_controller_constructor`:

> post_controller_constructor Called immediately after your controller is instantiated, but prior to any method calls happening.

Crie ***application/hooks/logged.php*** e ponha isso aqui:

```
function logged() {
    $ci = & get_instance();//Instância do CodeIgniter
    $method = $ci->router->fetch_class().'/'.$ci->router->fetch_method();//Método atual
    $protegidos = ['sistema/clientes'];//Métodos protegidos
    $usuario_logado = $ci->session->userdata('usuario_logado');//Array gerado pelo seu algotitmo de "login" e gravado na SESSION
    if (in_array($method, $protegidos)) {//Verificando se o método é protegido
        if (!$usuario_logado[username]) {//Verificando se o usuário está logado
            $ci->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'Autentique-se, por favor!');//Aqui vc tb pode criar um aviso pro usuário saber o motivo do comportamento da aplicação
            $url = base_url('controller/metodo_de_logon');
            redirect($url);//usuário não logado direciona para a pagina de login
        }
    }
}
```

Tem muito mais coisa que pode ser feita pra tornar esse *HOOK* mais seguro (confirmar um *hash* no banco de dados, confirmar o tempo de vida da sessão, etc), mas o básico referente à sua dúvida é isso.

Comment: Aliás, tempo de vida da sessão quem controla é a [Session Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-library). Por isso que é legal deixá-la ativada ;)

Comment: Fiz bem como você disse @ShutUpMagda, caso eu já esteja com o login feito e habilite os hooks, funciona perfeito, mas caso eu faça logout ele ja retorna o erro: Message: Undefined index: usuario_logado Filename: hooks/logged.php  Line Number: 7

Comment: Quando vc não está logado, ele não acha a $_SESSION['usuario_logado'] por motivos óbvios. A solução é verificar a sessão antes de atribuir: `if($_SESSION['usuario_logado']){$usuario_logado = $_SESSION['usuario_logado'];} else{$usuario_logado = NULL;}`. Editei a resposta ;)

Comment: Sim imaginei que seria algo assim, porem esta um pouco estranho pois ele esta entrando no if e no else de forma correta (testei utilizando die e simulando as duas situações logado/não logado) mas ainda assim ele retorna o mesmo erro de antes, sou novo aqui no SO também não se é permitido divulgar o projeto via git

Comment: Nome da variável. Isso depende de como vc está nomeando essa SESSION. Tem o github? Qual é? Fica até mais fácil se vc divulgar.

Comment: https://github.com/fmlima4/sistema

Comment: Bem, eu olhei o github, não vi nada. Você pode tentar usar `$ci->session->userdata('usuario_logado')` ao invés de  `$_SESSION['usuario_logado']`, ou `if(isset($_SESSION['usuario_logado'])){...` mas eu acho que dá no mesmo...

Comment: Ah, em  `buscaPorEmailSenha()` de `Usuarios_model` vc está retornando `row_array()`, mas eu acho que deveria ser `result_array()`.

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar a verificação se a sessão existe o melhor metodo seria:

```
if($this->session->has_userdata('usuario_logado') == true){
     echo "Logado.";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer:

```
if(isset($this->session->userdata('usuario_logado'))){
     echo "Logado.";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda andré, mas ao utilizar seu método recebo o seguinte erro Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)