# Codeigniter - Autenticação de Permissão

Tags: codeigniter, auth

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber se existe uma solução mais prática para o meu problema.

Cada usuário tem uma permissão diferente, caracterizada por um permissao_id na tabela usuários que é correlacionada com uma id na tabela permissão.

Existe uma forma mais prática de verificar a permissão do usuário em diversos métodos sem ter que ficar trabalhando com IF/ELSE?
Pra cada método exclusivo de cada permissão preciso ficar setando essas condições pra que outros usuários não consigam ter acesso ao método.

Obrigado!

Comment: Isso aqui: [Controle de sessions PHP com Codeigniter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180083/controle-de-sessions-php-com-codeigniter/180134#180134) deve ajudar a começar.

Answer (score -1):

Pode utilizar os hooks do codeigniter segue abaixo um exemplo

```
function restrict() {

 //Instância do CodeIgniter
 $ci = & get_instance();
 //Método atual, pega da url
 $method = $ci->router->fetch_class().'/'.$ci->router->fetch_method();

 //Métodos protegidos, aqui você especifica as funções protegidas
    $protegidos = ['funcao/index','funcao/inserir','funcao/editar', 
    'funcao/atualizar','funcao/deletar','funcao/pesquisar','funcao/exports'];

 //Array gerado pelo seu algotitmo de "login" e gravado na SESSION
    $usuario_logado = $ci->session->userdata('usuario_logado');
    if (in_array($method, $protegidos)) {//Verificando se o método é protegido
        if ($usuario_logado['cargo']!='admin') {//Verificando nivel de permissao do usuario
            $ci->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'Voçe nao possui privilegios');
//Aqui vc tb pode criar um aviso pro usuário saber o motivo do comportamento da aplicação
    ?>

    <script>
      alert('você nao possui autorização');
    </script>

<?php
    $var = "<script>javascript:history.back(-2)</script>";
    echo $var;
    } 
}
}
?>
```

pode criar varios hooks em cada um deles protegendo suas funçoes e dando acesso conforme permissao do usuarioP

Comment: Desse jeito aí não vai funcionar... ;-)

Comment: Realmente  não é a solução sobre medida, mas é o inicio para que ele pesquise e ajuste a sua necessidade

Comment: Não. Tá errado mesmo...

Comment: Eu vou dar uma olhada no link que você me mandou @ShutUpMagda!

Comment: @FelipeMirandaDeLima, obrigado pela ajuda também!!

Comment: Dá pra adaptar naquele _hook_ que mandei no link pra fazer rodar as permissões (o _hook_ só cuida de autenticação). É relativamente fácil. Se vc conseguir, posta a resposta aqui, ok? ;-)