# Problema ao utilizar hooks para controlar a autorização das paginas

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou tentando utilizar os `Hooks` do `Codeigniter` para impedir que acessem determinadas paginas sem estar logado. Para isso eu habilitei os `Hooks` e criei no arquivo **application\config\hooks.php** a seguinte estrutura para chamar o `Hook`.

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
 'class'    => 'Authenticate',
 'function' => 'check_user_login',
 'filename' => 'Authenticate.php',
 'filepath' => 'hooks',
 'params'   => array()
);
```

Dentro da pasta de `Hooks` eu criei o arquivo Authenticate.

**application\hooks\Authenticate.php**

```
<?php
class Authenticate{
public function __construct() {}

function check_user_login() {
 $ci = & get_instance();
 $method = $ci->router->fetch_class().'/'.$ci->router->fetch_method(); /* Na minha pagina de login o retorno é Login/index */
 $protegidos = ['dashboard/index']; /* Setei para proteger no momento somente o dashboard */
 $usuario_logado = $ci->session->userdata('usuario_logado');
   if (in_array($method, $protegidos)) {
    if (!$usuario_logado[username]) {
        $ci->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'Autentique-se, por favor!');
        redirect(APP_URL . 'login');
    }
}
}
}
?>
```

Porém quando tento logar ele me redireciona direto para pagina de login novamente e não entra no sistema.

Comment: Apesar de eu achar que isso já foi respondido ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180134/42307)), o problema é só o que está gravado na `SESSION` 'usuario_logado'. Obviamente, o _hook_ não está achando a variável `$usuario_logado[username]`.