# Problema com session no CodeIgniter após colocar site em nova hospedagem

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Estou com o seguinte problema: ao tentar realizar o *logon* em alguns navegadores ou até mesmo no celular (não ocorre em todos, meu amigo por exemplo consegue fazer o login normalmente), a sessão simplesmente não é iniciada e a pessoa continua deslogada.

Não há retorno de código de erro. Já mudei as configurações de sessão do `CodeIgniter` pra salvar em banco de dados, salvar em pasta, e nada resolve.

Gostaria da ajuda de quem manja de `CodeIgniter`, pois já testei diversas coisas. Deixo aqui algumas de minhas configurações, para ajudar:

**config.php**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

**Depois de digitar o formulário**

Envio o que ele digitou nos 2 campos e envio para o controller, no controller recebo eles assim:

```
$user = $this->input->post('user');
$senha = md5($this->input->post('senha'));
```

E envio para o model Login

```
$result = $this->login->entrar($user, $senha);
```

No model:

```
public function entrar($user, $senha){
        return $this->db->query('select *
                                 from usuario
                                 where (usuario = ? or email = ?)
                                 and senha = ?',array($user, $user, $senha))->row();
    }
```

Se a variavel de retorno não estiver vazia (obtiver resultado com o select) eu gravo a sessão que já está iniciada no autoload do CodeIgniter

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'database');
```

**Como eu gravo a sessão:** (`$result` é a varáivel que volta com os dados do usuário)

```
$this->session->set_userdata('id', $result->id);
$this->session->set_userdata('nome_completo', $result->nome_completo);
$this->session->set_userdata('email', $result->email);
$this->session->set_userdata('usuario', $result->usuario);
$this->session->set_userdata('senha', $result->senha);
```

**Após isso**
Quando dou o seguinte comando após gravar a sessão

```
print_r($this->session->userdata());
```

Obtenho a sessão gravada corretamente, mas após recarregar a página para atualizar os dados do usuario na tela a sessão não está setada, e o resultado do print_r é

```
array{}
```

**OBS:** Antes meu site estava no seguinte endereço: http://meulivro-teste.000webhostapp.com, agora comprei um pacote de hospedagem no hostinger, e ele está no site: http://www.conteumahistoria.com.

**Adicional**
A versão do PHP estava na 7.3 no hostinger, voltei para 7.1 para ver se corrigia, mas nada mudou

Comment: Não dá pra saber se vc está carregando a biblioteca do modo correto. Não dá pra saber de que maneira o _method_ está recuperando os dados. Não dá pra saber quais variáveis vc usa pra validar a sessão. Não dá pra saber como a sessão é validada no navegador (já que vc relata que em alguns, isso aí funciona). **Mostre o código**. Mostre, minimamente, como faz para gravar, recuperar e validar a sessão.

Comment: vou editar e complementar com os dados que você falou

Comment: Você já tentou carregar a librarie session no arquivo de configuração autoload.php?

Comment: Ela esta carregando no autoload, como mostrei ali em cima

Comment: Basicamente vc confirma se usuário e senha informados existem no banco, e se verdadeiro, recupera os dados do usuário do banco e os grava na sessão. **Mas qual é a _function/method_ que valida os dados gravados na sessão?** É esse o problema. Não basta vc gravar uma sessão com os dados do usuário, o `php` (ou o navegador) tem que saber pra que servem esses dados, se eles ainda são válidos ou se estão expidados, etc.

Comment: utilizo o metodo $this->session->has_userdata('nomequesalvei') que é padrão do codeigniter, se houver algo salvo como no campo 'nomequesalvei' da sessão ele retorna true

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Controle de sessions PHP com Codeigniter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180083/controle-de-sessions-php-com-codeigniter)

Comment: Este método não serve pra isso, e já está até obsoleto na nova versão do `CodeIgniter`. O `has_userdata($key)` só vai confirmar que um item de sessão existe, mas não controla autenticação. Eu acredito que sua pergunta seja uma duplicação dessa aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180083/controle-de-sessions-php-com-codeigniter. É exatamente o que vc está procurando...

Comment: Mas o problema não está em validar a sessão, mas sim que a sessão não é setada, logo depois de fazer login eu dou print_r na sessão toda e aparece a sessão, mas ao resetar a pagina e dar print_r($this->session->userdata()) não tem mais nada na sessão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte maneira: (vou responder minha própria pergunta para caso alguém venha a ter o mesmo problema possa tentar resolver da mesma maneira que eu resolvi)

**Na pasta application/config/config.php**

1 - Tirar o "_" do nome do cookie, pode ocorrer erros em alguns navegadores

```
$config[‘sess_cookie_name’] = ‘ci_session’;

// Mude para:
$config[‘sess_cookie_name’] = ‘cisession’;
```

2 - Mudar também a parte de cookies

```
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$config['cookie_domain'] = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost' ? '' : preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']));
$config['cookie_path'] = BASE_URI;
```

3 - Mudar a seguinte configuração

```
$config['base_url'] = BASE_URL;
```

**Agora vamos alterar o arquivo constants.php dentro da pasta config**

No fim do arquivo, adicione o seguinte codigo

```
// Base URL (keeps this crazy sh*t out of the config.php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
{
$base_url  = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ? 
'https' : 'http';
$base_url .= '://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', 
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

// Base URI (It's different to base URL!)
$base_uri = parse_url($base_url, PHP_URL_PATH);

if (substr($base_uri, 0, 1) != '/')
{
    $base_uri = '/'.$base_uri;
}

if (substr($base_uri, -1, 1) != '/')
{
    $base_uri .= '/';
}
 }

else
{
 $base_url = 'http://localhost/';
 $base_uri = '/';
}

 // Define these values to be used later on
 define('BASE_URL', $base_url);
 define('BASE_URI', $base_uri);
 define('APPPATH_URI', BASE_URI.APPPATH);

 // We dont need these variables any more
  unset($base_uri, $base_url);
```

**CRÉDITOS A https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-37828.html**